# Solve the Bessel Equation to show it satisfies the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I am required to show that the function:

$y(x)=\sqrt{x} \times J_{\frac{1}{4}}{(kx^2/2)}$ - which involves a Bessel function of order $\frac{1}{4}$

satisfies the differential equation of the form:

$y'' + k^2x^2y = 0$

I have used reduction of order - $y(x)= u(x)\sqrt{x}$ - and differentiating, then subbing into the differential equation I get the following equation, which is in the form:

$4x^2 u′′(x) + 4x u′(x)+ (4k^2x^4 − 1)u(x) = 0$

I then tried letting $t = (kx^2)/2$ but I can't get the Bessel Equation of order $\frac{1}{4}$.

Can someone please help me with getting the solution to the Bessel Equation. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you use MathJax to format your questions for readability. A basic guide can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: thanks, im only new to this and havent had much practice

Comment: It's fine - we've all been new at some point! Just suggesting MathJax as it makes it easier for users to answer your question. I've submitted an edit that converts your math into MathJax, and if you want to, you can approve that.

Answer (score 1):

You got (which is correct) :
$$4x^2 u′′(x) + 4x u′(x)+ (4k^2x^4 − 1)u(x) = 0$$
Then change of variable :
$$t=\frac{kx^2}{2}\quad\to\quad \frac{dt}{dx}=kx$$
$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=kx\frac{du}{dt}$

$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(kx\frac{du}{dt}\right)=
k\frac{du}{dt}+kx\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}\frac{dt}{dx}=k\frac{du}{dt}+k^2x^2\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}$
$$4x^2 \left(k\frac{du}{dt}+k^2x^2\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}\right) + 4x\left(kx\frac{du}{dt}\right)+ (4k^2x^4 − 1)u = 0$$

$$4k^2x^4\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+8kx^2\frac{du}{dt} + (4k^2x^4 − 1)u = 0$$

$$16t^2\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+16t\frac{du}{dt} + (16t^2 − 1)u = 0$$
$$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+\frac{1}{t}\frac{du}{dt} + (1 − \frac{1}{16t^2})u = 0$$
Compare to the Bessel's equation :
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}J_\nu(t)+\frac{1}{t}\frac{d}{dt}J_\nu(t) + (1 − \frac{\nu^2}{t^2})J_\nu(t) = 0$$
$\nu^2=\frac{1}{16}\quad\to\quad \nu=\frac{1}{4}\quad\to\quad u=J_{1/4}(t)=J_{1/4}\left(\frac{kx^2}{2}\right)\quad\to\quad y=\sqrt(x)J_{1/4}\left(\frac{kx^2}{2}\right)$